# Windows offline - Change User Language with downloaded language packages

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, package, dism

I have a Windows PC, with Windows 11 Enterprise 23H2 installed, and an English System language.

I want to add a new language, for example, Chinese, and make it the System language instead.

This PC has no network or internet access, so I have to download *Languages and Optional Features for Windows 11, version 22H2 and 23H2* from Microsoft:

This ISO File contains a lot of `*.cab`- Files. For a language like Chinese, (and English too), those are the following six files:

- Client-Language-Pack
- LanguageFeatures-Basic
- LanguageFeatures-Handwriting
- LanguageFeatures-OCR
- LanguageFeatures-Speech
- LanguageFeatures-TextToSpeech

I add every single package of from the above with a command in cmd.exe like:

```bash
DISM /NoRestart /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:"C:\Path\to\my\Language-Pack.cab"
```

Then I can check that the languages were added/installed properly with the following command in cmd.exe:

```bash
DISM /online /get-intl
```

Next I try to change the language with the following commands using PowerShell:

```
Set-Culture zh-CN
Set-WinSystemLocale zh-CN
Set-WinUserLanguageList zh-CN -Force
```

The final step is to reboot. If I do this, and logon again, I see a system which is not completely translated; i.e. the Welcome screen still shows 'Welcome' instead of some Chinese symbols. In the Windows settings symbols on the left side, which are normally English, are in English. However, if I navigate deeper, a lot of things are in Chinese, as intended.

I want to know, is there something I can do to change the entire System language, and not just some parts of it?

Could it may be that I've forgotten to install some packages? Or is there a setting missing, which I could enable?

I also tried to skip the PowerShell commands, and instead tried to click the install button in Windows settings, because only the default language was displayed there, (until the "install" button was clicked and after a second). The packages do appear as "installed" in the Windows settings GUI.

Comment: mount your english image with dism. Then add the above packages and set the default language and locale. Unmount the image and install it to your PC.

Answer (score 0):

```
dism.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath=Microsoft-Windows-Client-Language-Pack_x64_zh-cn.cab /norestart

dism.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath=Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Basic-zh-cn-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab /norestart

$UserLanguageList = Get-WinUserLanguageList

$UserLanguageList.Add("zh-CN")

Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList $UserLanguageList -Force 
 -WarningAction:SilentlyContinue

Install-Language zh-CN
```

Comment: Please do not post a code only answer. This requires some body text to better describe that code, and how the OP can use it to solve their stated issue.